# Is there a way to have Delay timer or cutscene? Unity March 28/21 update

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What I'm trying to do is have my player stop moving so I can play animation through a trigger-event or just a custscene.

What I expect was for one of them to trigger the timer then play animation>player move.. like a cut-scene

Also there are no errors In any of them They just didn't stop player from moving or just stop the player when starting the game(or when I press play it just set forwardMovement to 0)

Here's the code I use:

```
public class Player_controls : MonoBehaviour 
{
using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.UIElements;
    
    public class Player_controls : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public  int forwardMovement = 1000;
     
        public void Update()
        {
            rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardMovement * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }




}
```

Things that I tried:

```
public void ForwardMovement()
{
    forwardMovement = 0;
    Invoke("Action", 2f);
}

public void Action ()
{
    forwardMovement = 1000 ;
}
```

Which only works for `ForwardMovement();` method nothing else

I tried these two things also:

```
Public static class MonoExtensions
{
    using System.Collections;
    using  System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using System;
        
    public float Delayer = 10f;

    public static class MonoExtensions
    {
        public static void Timed_delay(this MonoBehaviour mono,Action function, float Delayer)
        {
            mono.StartCoroutine(Timed_delayRoutine(function,Delayer));
        }
        
        static IEnumerator Timed_delayRoutine(Action function, float Delayer)
        {
            yield  return new WaitForSeconds(Delayer);
            function();
}




public class `Player_Controls`: MonoBehaviour
{
public void PM ()
    {
        forwardMovement = 0;
    }
    
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (CompareTag("Power_up"))
        {
            this.Timed_delay(PM, Delayer);
        }
    }

}
```

Which just stop the player from moving an nothing else.

What I also tried was:

```
public class Player_Controls : MonoBehaviour
{
void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(ForwardMovement());     
    }

    IEnumerator ForwardMovement()
    {
        forwardMovement = 0;
        yield return new waitforseconds(Delayer);
        forwardMovement = 1050;
    } 

    void OnTriggerEnter(collider other)
    {
        if (CompareTag("Power_up"))
        {
            ForwardMovement();
        }
    }

}
```

Which did not work as in(it works but the timer part does nothing, so the player can't move when started the game )

```
Different way I tried 
public class Player_Controls : MonoBehaviour
{
 OnTriggerEnter(collider other)
    {
        Startcroutine(ForwardMovement ));
    }
}
```

it didn't work but no Errors.

I tried this one by jazzhar:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;

    public class Player_controls : MonoBehaviour
    {
        // Drag the player in the inspector here;
        public Rigidbody rb;

        // Youre speed variable for movement.
        public float Speed = 5;

        // Youre speed variable for movement.
        public int forwardMovement = 1000;

        // Set this "stopmoving" bool to true to prevent movement.
        public bool stopMoving = false;

        // Create and select the right layer in the inspector.
        public LayerMask WichObjectStopsMovement;

        public void Update()
        {
            // if stopMoving = true than Dont Add force.
            if (stopMoving == false)
            {
                rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardMovement * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
            }

        }

        private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
        {
           // if you're player touches a object and that object's layer
           // is the same as "WichObjectStopsMovement" than disable Movement.
           if (collision.collider.gameObject.layer == WichObjectStopsMovement)
           {
                stopMoving = false;
           }
       }
   }
```

It sorta works in a way if you set if

```
 if (stopMoving == true)
                {
                    rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardMovement * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
                }
```

and

```
if (collision.collider.gameObject.layer == WichObjectStopsMovement)
               {
                    stopMoving = true;
               }
```

then the player would be able to move but it will not trigger if hit the cube

it didn't work either but no Errors.

And some other timers I did but forgotten....

**_________________________________________________________________March/6/21**

```
public float Delayer = 10.0f;
```

I think found solution by doing this

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
        {
            if (CompareTag("Power_up"))
            {
                Delayer -= Time.deltaTime; <- this part giving me the error

                if (Delayer => 0)
                {
                    forwardMovement = 0;
                }
            }
```

}

but their one problem  it giving me the this error `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'bool' because it is not a delegate type [Assembly-CSharp]csharp(CS1660)` I don't know much about this even searching about doesn't help either

**__________________________________________________________________March 28/21**

this script is under player controls

this one works I made sure by doing  `Debug.Log("test");`
void OnTriggerExit(Collider collision)
{
if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Power_up"))
{
forwardMovement = 0;
}
if (forwardMovement <= 0)
{
Debug.Log("test");
}

Comment: 1. Please include the errors you're getting with these attempts. 2. When you're writing [tag:c#] code, capitalization, spelling, and syntax matter. `waitforseconds` should be `WaitForSeconds`, `Startcroutine` should be `StartCoroutine`, and `ForwardMovement )` should be `ForwardMovement()`.

Comment: @marc_s none of them gave me errors it just either didn't stop player from moving or just stop compete when started the game without triggering the tag

Answer (score 0):

This might be a solution to you're problem, Fire-Source!:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;

    public class Player_controls : MonoBehaviour
    {
        // Drag the player in the inspector here;
        public Rigidbody rb;

        // Youre speed variable for movement.
        public float Speed = 5;

        // Youre speed variable for movement.
        public int forwardMovement = 1000;

        // Set this "stopmoving" bool to true to prevent movement.
        public bool stopMoving = false;

        // Create and select the right layer in the inspector.
        public LayerMask WichObjectStopsMovement;

        public void Update()
        {
            // if stopMoving = true than Dont Add force.
            if (stopMoving == false)
            {
                rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardMovement * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
            }

        }

        private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
        {
           // if youre player touches a object and that object's layer
           // is the same as "WichObjectStopsMovement" than disable Movement.
           if (collision.collider.gameObject.layer == WichObjectStopsMovement)
           {
                stopMoving = false;
           }
       }
   }
```

This code uses a LayerMask, to create 1 click on any object and in the inspector go:

Click on Layer:
Add Layer:
Write in User Layer 6, StopMovement (or anything else).

Than in the object that should stop player movement:
Click on layer:
Than select the Layer that says StopMovement.

And in you're player's script drag the object into the rb variable.
and in "WichObjectStopsMovement" assign the StopMovement layer.

This should take care of everything is that ok?

Comment: so how exactly  am I supposed to trigger it? Since I have check it to make it stop instead the `OntriggerEnter(Collider other){ }` or if I need a trigger at all

Comment: So if i understand you correctly you want to stop the movement of you touch a specific object?

Comment: basically that's what exactly I want do to

Comment: Sorry for my slow reply's, I believe our timezones are opposites so I only have now to fix it, ill edit my comment with you're answer.

Comment: it's no problem, just takes time

Comment: I commented the code, I hope you understand how it works.

Comment: I did eveything you said and yet it still doesn't set to the trigger. I'll make a video to show if did I something wrong... here's the video link: https://youtu.be/G4fsfQceAt4

Comment: what I mean by it's not set to the trigger is that it works but it doesn't. Also didn't mean to sound harsh in the other comment, however you take it.

Comment: I found a problem with your code is that, because the mask layer has no reference and so it will tell the game to stop the player as soon as possible in playmode.  the problem was I need to be `CompareWithTag` or somethin like that to make that work

Comment: 2/2  the problem is that it needs to be `CompareWithTag`, `setactive();` or it's something like that  Also test your code before posting an answer and the version I'm using is 20201.1.0f1